# Checking a type constructor function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I am using `Object.create()` to create new prototypes and I would like to check the constructor function used for an object.

OBJECT.constructor only returns the inherited prototype :

```
var mytype = function mytype() {}
mytype.prototype = Object.create( Object.prototype, { } );
//Returns "Object", where I would like to get "mytype"
console.log( ( new mytype ).constructor.name );
```

How to do this (without using any external library) ?

(My end goal is to create new types derived from Object, and being able to check the types of instantiated objects at runtime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mytype = function mytype() {}
mytype.prototype = Object.create( Object.prototype, { } );
```

After assigning a new object to `mytype.prototype`, `mytype.prototype.constructor` property is overridden by `Object.prototype.constructor` So you have to change `mytype.prototype.constructor` back to `mytype`

```
mytype.prototype.constructor = mytype;
```

It restores the `.constructor` property that was on the original prototype object that you overwrote. You should restore it because it's expected to be there.

```
//Returns "Object", where I would like to get "mytype"
console.log( ( new mytype ).constructor.name );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had no idea about this !